# I am trying to do a Read More button, but I just started using javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, expand

I want to do a Read More button, which will expand the page and the text will appear with a nice animation. I tried doing a jquery code but I realised that it was not going to work and I deleted it. The Read More button will appear if the text is bigger than 200 characters. I only have something basic like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3RR/82/).

Javascript code:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
 $("#hidden").show();
});
```

Comment: There are already tons of examples. Have a look over here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpn94/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you need to write a logic like:
1: Check the string length if you are using PHP then a login could be something like the below:

```
 <?php $str = "I am in love with PHP";
if(strlen($str) > 10)
{
  $showten = substr($str, 0, 10);
echo $showten . "<a href="#" class='readmore'>Readmore</a>";
}
 ?>



<div class="all-content"><?php echo $str; ?></div>
```

Now comes the Jquery into action:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.readmore').click(function()
{
    $(this).closest("div").find(".all-content").toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

This is a sample code, you need to make minor modifcations as per your requirement!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this :

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use many jquery functions like `show(),fadeIn(),slideDown(),animate()` you can even use css transitions

Answer (score 1):

You can find different jquery animation here.

```
http://api.jquery.com/animate/
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $("#hidden").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a {
      color: #0254EB
    }

    a:visited {
      color: #0254EB
    }

    a.morelink {
      text-decoration: none;
      outline: none;
    }

    .morecontent span {
      display: none;
    }

    .comment {
      width: 400px;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="comment more">
    <a href="http://eqlits.com">When a text is too long to fit, We can cut it short and add a "Read More" OR "Link" button.
       Clicking on this button will show the Next Page.</a>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum laoreet, nunc eget laoreet sagittis, quam ligula sodales
    orci, congue imperdiet eros tortor ac lectus. Duis eget nisl orci. Aliquam mattis purus non mauris blandit id luctus
    felis convallis. Integer varius egestas vestibulum. Nullam a dolor arcu, ac tempor elit. Donec.
  </div>
  <div class="comment more">
      <a href="http://eqlits.com">When a text is too long to fit, We can cut it short and add a "Read More" OR "Link" button.
        Clicking on this button will show the Next Page.</a>
    Duis nisl nibh, egestas at fermentum at, viverra et purus. Maecenas lobortis odio id sapien facilisis elementum. Curabitur
    et magna justo, et gravida augue. Sed tristique pellentesque arcu quis tempor.
  </div>
  <div class="comment more">
      <a href="http://eqlits.com">When a text is too long to fit, We can cut it short and add a "Read More" OR "Link" button.
        Clicking on this button will show the Next Page.</a>
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit nunc sed sem dictum id feugiat quam blandit. Donec nec sem sed arcu interdum commodo
    ac ac diam. Donec consequat semper rutrum. Vestibulum et mauris elit. Vestibulum mauris lacus, ultricies.
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    'use strict';
    function truncate(str, maxlength) {
      return (str.length > maxlength) ?
        str.slice(0, maxlength - 1) + `<input type='button' id='more' class="btnmore" value='Link'/>   ` : str;
    }

    let data = document.getElementsByClassName("more");
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let str = data[i].innerHTML;

      document.getElementsByClassName("more")[i].innerHTML = truncate(str, 300);
      document.getElementsByClassName("btnmore")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementsByClassName("more")[i].innerHTML = str;
      })
    }




  </script>
</body>

</html>
```